# Installing app.js error Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to install `app.js` to create an HTTP server, but this version is from the old `Express version (3.x)` and so he install a version deprecated, that uses commands that are no longer functional, like `app.configure()` and even others, but I don't know how to make work this code to the new version.

**My code :**

**app.js**

```
/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var express = require('express')
  , routes = require('./routes');

var app = module.exports = express.createServer();

// Configuration

app.configure(function(){
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
});

app.configure('development', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler({ dumpExceptions: true, showStack: true }));
});

app.configure('production', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
});

// Routes

app.get('/', routes.index);

app.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log("Express server listening on port %d in %s mode", app.address().port, app.settings.env);
});
```

**layout.jade**

```
!!!
html
  head
    title= title
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
  body!= body
```

He points out some error like :

> 500 Error: C:\Users\Leandro Mont\Desktop\Lucas\Node\Professional Node\my_app/views/layout.jade:1 > 1| !!! 2| html 3| head 4| title= title `!!!` is deprecated, you must now use `doctype`

What are the modifications that I need to do, to make it work ?

Comment: That error is from the template file. Please post the jade file content (`layout.jade`).

Comment: You should use a newer, non-deprecated system.

Comment: And what system could I use to make this error go away ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `!!!` (which is deprecated, as the error says), use `doctype`:

```
doctype html
html
  head
    title= title
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
  body!= body
```